# Passing Javascript variable to Django views.py with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I currently have a javascript variable called myVariableToSend that contains a single string and I need to send to my views where I can make raw SQL queries to gather corresponding data from the database and bring it back to my javascript. Here is what I have:

**Javascript:**

```
function scriptFunction(myVariableToSend){

        $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/getData/", myVariableToSend, function(serverdata){
        window.alert(serverdata);
});
```

**Views.py:**

```
def getData(request):
    some_data = request.GET(myVariableToSend)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT Car_ID FROM cars WHERE Carname = %s ", [some_data])
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    return JsonResponse(row, safe = False)
```

**Urls.py:**

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', startpage),
url(r'^getData/$', getData ),
```

I don't think my server side script(views.py) is working because when I run my server, I get a http500 error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I have found that when I comment out my entire Views.py and only put

```
def getData(request):

return JsonResponse({"hello":"World"}, safe = False)
```

I get no problems and the AJAX request works. But when I have my original getData, it doesn't work. When I add this line in my views.py:

```
some_data = request.GET(myVariableToSend)
```

, I get an error and the data isn't displayed

Comment: Why are using a raw SQL query? Haven't you figured out Django's core feature ORM, yet? Then you should really do the tutorials.

Comment: Yes I know about Django's ORM, but I want to do it this way. Its for learning purposes.

Comment: You should set DEBUG to True. If you did, you'd see you get a NameError in the first line of that function, because the variable myVariableToSend is not defined.

Comment: myVariableToSend is defined by within another javascript function that calls this function scriptFunction.

Comment: No, the *Python* function.

Comment: Oh I see. Would I have to declare a GET dictionary in my python function?

Comment: No, you just need to use syntatically correct Python: `some_data = request.GET('myVariableToSend')`

Comment: request.GET('myVariableToSend') is also BAD syntax. It would have to be request.GET.get('myVariableToSend') or request.GET['myVariableToSend']

Comment: Also, this line cursor.execute("SELECT Car_ID FROM cars WHERE Carname = %s ", [some_data]) is problematic. It needs to be cursor.execute("SELECT Car_ID FROM cars WHERE Carname = %s ", % some_data)

Comment: I am getting a syntax error when I do  cursor.execute("SELECT Car_ID FROM cars WHERE Carname = %s ", % some_data)

Comment: Argh, @user4426017 is **wrong** and that is something you should **never** do. The original syntax for the SQL query was fine there.

Comment: okay I corrected it, but I still am getting a http500 error.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my URL but I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to send ur variables to function in view, u can capture it with url, like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getData/' + myVariableToSend +'/', function (serverdata) { //do ur work}
```

Then in urls.py you have:

```
url(r'getData/(?P<my_var>\w+)/$', views.get_data, name='get_data')
```

Then views.py:

```
def get_data(request, my_var):
#do ur work here
```

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to send data through URL instead of through request?

Comment: If ur data is sensitive, then maybe it is. I use this solution in my project, but the data which I send through URL is not private.

Comment: Is there a way to go about this by passing data with request instead of url? I appreciate your answer, but I just would like to see how the other way would be done. Thank you.

Comment: I changed everything to what you put and I am getting a 404 error now.

Answer (score 1):

**Answering the original question:**

Your server is failing probably because bad syntax in views.py

```
some_data = request.GET(myVariableToSend)
```

`myVariableToSend` is undefined here. So you should get it like this:

```
some_data = request.GET['myVariableToSend']
```

**Besides the original question:**

You'll get a lot of headaches if you try to set up your django app like this.You can query your database way easier if you use django's ORM. Read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/db/queries/).

Also, if you want to send the data in your models to your javascript code, you can save yourself lots of time by using a framework like [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).